# SCNParticleSystem weak variable at [addressX] holds [addressY]

Tags: scenekit, swift4.2

I began receiving this error after converting to swift 4.2.  Prior to that, there were no issues.  Once the object is removed from an array, the error repeats.  If I take the emitter out, no issues.

It doesn't appear to be losing memory nor does it crash.

objc[1207]: __weak variable at 0x137ef2220 holds 0x137ef0040 instead of 0x137ef1fc0. This is probably incorrect use of objc_storeWeak() and objc_loadWeak(). Break on objc_weak_error to debug.

```
class BaseObject
{
    var emitterExplosion1 = SCNParticleSystem()

    //********************************************************************
    init()
    {
        emitterExplosion1       = gNodes.createEmitter(vParticleType: .explosion1)
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've been getting this too. Creating a symbolic break just gives you the mentioned codes again. It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it is happening (a bug perhaps?), but after a lot trial and error I found that this occurs every time a new particle system is declared in your code. The workaround is to declare the particle system as an optional and then handle it later. You will instead need to declare and update the emitter rather than create a new one. For example:

```
var emitterExplosion1 : SCNParticleSystem?
init(){
    emitterExplosion1 = SCNParticleSystem()
}
updateEmitter(emitter: emitterExplosion1)
```

It's annoying if you have 100 different particles flying off everywhere, but if you only have a few to manage and hate having your error console filled, I found this works.

Comment: Yeah, pretty annoying.  I managed to get the first error to clear up with your example, but the others are still showing up even with the change.  Agree, must be a bug.  Good answer though, thank you!